# Como alterar o nome do banco de dados no MySQL Workbench 8.0 usando ALTER DATABASE?

Tags: mysql

Tenho um banco de dados chamada `teste` com umas 3 tabelas e eu **queria mudar o nome do banco de dados** de `teste` para `novoteste`. Eu acho que isso se faz com `ALTER DATABASE` só que eu não conheço esse comando.

Comment: Linux ou Windows?

Comment: Seria mais pra SGBD, mas eu uso MySQL Workbench no linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No **PostgreSQL** é o seguinte:

Para alterar o **nome** do banco de dados:

`ALTER DATABASE <nome_do_banco> RENAME TO <novo_nome_do_banco>`

Para alterar o nome do **schema** do banco de dados:

`ALTER SCHEMA <nome_do_schema> RENAME TO <novo_nome_do_schema>`

No **MySQL** é o seguinte:

Criando um banco de dados:

```
CREATE DATABASE teste0;
```

Criando outro banco de dados:

```
CREATE DATABASE teste1;
```

setando o banco de dados que vai ocorrer a codificação:

```
USE teste0;
```

Criando uma tabela no banco **teste0**:

```
CREATE TABLE dados(
   id_codigo int primary key not null auto_increment,
   nome varchar (50)
);
```

Verificando a(s) tabela(s) no banco **teste0**

```
SHOW TABLES;
```

Usando o `RENAME TABLE` para tranferir a tabela do banco **teste0** para **teste1**:

```
RENAME TABLE teste0.id_codigo TO teste1.id_codigo,
             teste0.nome TO teste1.nome
```

setando o banco de dados **teste1**:

```
USE teste1;
```

Verificando a(s) tabela(s) no banco **teste1**

```
SHOW TABLES;
```

setando o banco de dados **teste0** (para verificar):

```
USE teste0;
```

Verificando a(s) tabela(s) no banco **teste0** (para verificar, mas não vai ter nada)

```
SHOW TABLES;
```

Caso queira apagar o antigo banco de dados vazio:

```
DROP DATABASE teste0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Não existe um comando único no MySQL para renomear um database.
Você pode utilizar o comando:

```
RENAME TABLE banco_atual.nome_tabela TO novo_banco.nome_tabela;
```

para cada uma das tabelas de banco_atual que, para efeitos práticos, será como se tivesse renomeado o banco, exceto pelo fato de que banco_atual continuar existindo, mas sem nenhuma tabela.
Posteriormente você pode rodar um `DROP DATABASE`.

Comment: [Documentação MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-database.html) usei esse comando para mudar o nome do banco de dados do  e o schema do PostgreSQL e funcionou, como assim não existe no MySQL Workbench?

Comment: De https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/rename-table.html: "Using this method to move all tables from one database to a different one in effect renames the database (an operation for which MySQL has no single statement), except that the original database continues to exist, albeit with no tables."

Comment: Então quer dizer que na antigo banco de dados sem tabelas pode excluí-lo seguindo o `RENAME TABLE` porque todas as tabelas foram para um novo banco de dados?

Answer (score 1):

Utilizar o comando para renomear um database no mysql costuma gerar muita dor de cabeça...

Em vez disso há duas alternativas:

a) Criar um novo database com o nome que você deseja e então copiar todas as tabelas do database original para o novo database. Depois disso é só apagar o database original.

b) Criar um dump do database original e depois importá-lo com o novo nome. Depois você apaga o database original.

Answer (score -1):

Opa boa tarde, por comando eu não sei, mas tem como alterar o nome do database pelo phpMyAdmin indo em Login -> Schemas -> Operations -> Rename Database.

Abraços.

Comment: Não uso o phpMyAdmin, uso o MySQL no linux com o `mysql-server` e `mysql-client`